# Problems with next-line autoscrolling

Tags: emacs

I am getting problem with autoscrolling with next-line in emacs. When i get to the edge of the screen 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfqEL.png
and making next-line sometimes I am not scrolled, and pointer aims to the center of the CURRENT screen, not the NEXT screen. https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPbuC.png
 (so if i hold C-n pointer will run endlessly through this screen)

I am getting same things with forward-line, sometimes with forward-page. I am not getting the same with previous-line autoscrolling, it works fine.

I don't know why. I only noticed, that when I have more long lines, and screen is splited vertically, this thing happens very fast(C-x 3 C-x 3, scrolling from the beginning of my 1000-lines .emasc file is a fast way to reproduce this bug).

Emacs -Q, (setq truncate-lines nil) doesn't have it. Emacs, (setq truncate-lines t) doesn't have it too.

If you know anything about what can cause this troubles, please reply.

Comment: Are you saying that setting `truncate-lines` to `nil` prevents the problem from occurring?

Comment: @phils oops, mistake in the question text. Thank you for pointing. No. `(setq truncate-lines t)` prevents(so long lines aren't fully on screen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2-hour using `eval-region` (this problem wasn't easy to reproduce, macro/elisp with `(next-line) (sit-for 0.01)` didn't give any effect, so I tested it each time by holding C-n, using binary search method for `eval-region`)

So the answer is:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightParentheses

Evaluating this in a `*scratch*`, starting emacs with `emacs -Q`

```
(setq-default truncate-lines nil)
(setq truncate-partial-width-windows nil)
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/my_path_to_highlight-parentheses_script/")
(require 'highlight-parentheses)
```

Make some buffer with long lines and narrow it with `C-x 3 C-u 5 0 C-x }` then `C-x o M-x highlight-parentheses-mode` and hold `C-n` is a way to reproduce the bug.

I commented out all thing relative with highlight-parentheses, and bug gone away. I think, I should find a way to tell developers about this bug.

Comment: I have had the same (or very similar) problem, and just submitted a bug to the maintainer.

Answer (score 1):

One potential source for this issue seems to be setting the `scroll-conservatively` variable.

http://groups.google.com/group/gnu.emacs.help/browse_thread/thread/0a7a9c730c037d57

> > I noticed that when moving down through big files, *sometimes* the
> >     cursor will jump from bottom of screen to middle.
> >
> > Any idea why this would happen only some of the time?
>
> Because Emacs' redisplay is unable to keep with the scrolling. Before
>   23.1, with scroll-conservatively set to a large value, Emacs never
>   jumped; now it tries no to do it, but sometimes it fails. I think the
>   relevant ChangeLog entry is this one:
>
> 2008-10-27  Chong Yidong
>
> ```
>     * xdisp.c (try_scrolling): When computing the distance from the
>     scroll margin to PT, try moving some distance past the window
>     bottom before giving up.
>
> Juanma
> ```

Comment: `scroll-conservatively is a variable defined in 'C source code'. Its value is 0` Seems to be different problem. I can reproduce this, setting `scroll-conservatively` to `9999`, but this problems actually different. In this link problem, screen is suddenly recentered(but with right position of the pointer), in my screen stands still and don't move at all(so `next-line` jumps up, which is wrong). This is VERY annoying, it crashed my macro edits for many times.